# Rounded Corner Not Showing in Table

Tags: html, css

I have this table and was trying to add rounded corners to it, but nothing happens. Could someone take a look and tell me where I'm going wrong? The size of the corner images are 14px each.

Any help would be appreciated greatly.

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
    <tr bgcolor="#e4322d" style="line-height: 0px">
        <td width="14px" height="14px"><img src="red1.png" width="14px" height="14px" alt=""></td>
        <td width="430" style="font-size: .2em">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="14px" height="14px"><img src="red2.png" width="14px" height="14px" alt=""></td>
    </tr>

    <tr bgcolor="#e4322d">
        <td width="14px" style="font-size: 1px">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="430" bgcolor="#e4322d" align="center" style="color: white; font-size: 16px"><span style="font-family: Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif; color:#FFFFFF;"><br>Come swim in our latest pool.<br><br></span></td>
        <td width="14px" height="14px" style="font-size: 1px;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

    <tr bgcolor="#e4322d" style="line-height: 0px">
        <td width="14" height="14"><img src="red3.png" width="14" height="14" alt=""></td>
        <td width="430" style="font-size: 0px;" height="2"></td>
        <td width="14px" height="14"><img src="red4.png" width="14" height="14" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real problem is that you are going complete overkill on the HTML for this.  You can make the whole thing simply with this HTML:

```
<div class="banner">Come swim in our latest pool.</div>
```

And add this CSS which takes care of all the styling:

```
.banner {
    width: 450px;
    padding: 35px 0;
    background: #E4322D;
    border-radius: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

It looks like you aren't using CSS, and are using the very old-fashioned and long outdated HTML technique of making everything with tables. There is no need.  I would take the time to quickly learn CSS.  It will change your life! Start here; it's easy to learn:

http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Training/What_is_CSS

And by using CSS and having a global stylesheet for your site, you will be able to reuse styles without having to write new code for it every time.  For example, you could have multiple banners that look the same as your "Come swim in our latest pool" one simply by giving them the same class:

```
<div class="banner">Come swim in our latest pool.</div>
<div class="banner">Also, check out this!</div>
<div class="banner">Hey, this box looks the same as the other two!</div>
```

Comment: Thanks alot for this advice. It's already changed my life as well speak.

Comment: Just wanted to say that this question, answer, and resulting "life change" filled me with unexpected CSS-nerd happiness! :D